# Nagios error because my bash script

Tags: bash, nagios

someone call tell me if this code make any sence and why give me that error?

```
#!/bin/sh
MyUSER="XXXX"                                 # USERNAME
MyPASS="XXXX"                                 # PASSWORD
MyHOST="XXXXX.XXXX.XXX.XXXX"      # HOST


OLD_NUM='mysql -u[$MyUSER] -p[$MyPASS] -h[$MyHOST] -e [SELECT ROW_COUNT() FROM dbo.User]'

while true
do
        sleep 5m
        NEW_NUM='mysql -u[$MyUSER] -p[MyPASS] -h[$MyHOST] -e [SELECT ROW_COUNT() FROM dbo.User]'

        if [ "$OLD_NUM" != "$NEW_NUM" ]
        then
                echo "WARNING - before $OLD_NUM , after $NEW_NUM "

        else
                echo " OK -  $OLD_NUM"

        fi

        OLD_NUM="$NEW_NUM"
done
```

i try to restart my nagios and give me this error:

> Processing object config file '/etc/nagios3/commands.cfg'... Error:
>   Invalid command object directive 'comand_line'. Error: Could not add
>   object property in file '/etc/nagios3/commands.cfg' on line 126.
>   Error processing object config files!

and my command.cfg in line 126 is:

```
#check_N_utilizadores_sql
define command {
command_name    check_N_utilizadores_sql
comand_line     /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_N_utilizadores_sql.sh
}
```

Comment: `command_line` is spelled with two `m`s

Comment: Why do you expect either of `$OLD_NUM` or `$NEW_NUM` to ever change? You are comparing two literal strings starting with `mysql`. Probably you meant to *execute* the command? The syntax for that is `\`mysql\`` or better `$(mysql)`.

Comment: well that 2 variables is a clients i have at the moment, if someone sign in in my website, will add +1 in my DB so i need to send a warning to nagios

Comment: and yes, i want to execute that line, but i dont know if i'm doing right

Answer (score 1):

You must write

```
command_line     /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_N_utilizadores_sql.sh
```

not `comamd_line`.
That is exactly what the message

```
Error: Invalid command object directive 'comand_line'.
```

says.

Comment: but still not work on nagios =(
Service Check Timed Out

Comment: @user3161343: Please add additional info to your question